# GTK2 - Draggable box

Tags: ruby, gtk, draggable

This may be a newbie question, but I am looking for a way to make a draggable box in GTK. I'm not talking about drag and drop, I just want to be able to move it around. Kind of in the style of [this](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check out the [Goocanvas](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/stable/) library. I don't know if there are bindings for this to Ruby-GTK2, but consider switching to GTK3 and GObject introspection anyway - you'll have access to a lot more libraries in Ruby.

The general idea would be to create a `GooCanvasRect` or other `GooCanvasItem`, connect to its  `button-press-event`, `button-release-event`, and `motion-notify-event` signals, and move it around the canvas accordingly.